# Sending content as it's loads in .Net

Tags: .net

I'm creating a simple ajax call to retrieve a list of user reviews. I want to have my aspx page output the content for each review item as it is processed. For example, lets say I had 100 reviews to show, how would I send the markup as it processes on the server end? In PHP I can do this with the flush() or ob_flush() function. What is the .NET equilvalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set Response.[BufferOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.bufferoutput.aspx) = false or you can call Response.[Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.flush.aspx)() to send the current buffered output.